# JQuery - is there a way to make less calls to the dom

Tags: jquery, get

i have this jquery function

```
    function update_prices(that, current_id, quantity) {
         //that == $(this)
        var wrapper = that.parents(".wrapper");
        var standard = wrapper.find(".prettyCheckbox small:eq(0)").parents("span").parents("label").prev("input").val();
        var professional = wrapper.find(".prettyCheckbox small:eq(1)").parents("span").parents("label").prev("input").val();
        var premium = wrapper.find(".prettyCheckbox small:eq(2)").parents("span").parents("label").prev("input").val();
        $.get("/shop_possystems/index.php?route=module/cart/ajax_get_individual_prices&standard_id=" + standard + "&professional_id" + professional + "&premium_id" + premium + "&quantity" + quantity;
            function(data) {
                var standard_price = data[0];
                var professional_price = data[0];
                var premium_price = data[0];
        });
        wrapper.find(".prettyCheckbox small:eq(0)").text(standard_price);
        wrapper.find(".prettyCheckbox small:eq(1)").text(professional_price);
        wrapper.find(".prettyCheckbox small:eq(2)").text(premium_price);
        return true;
    }
```

and i feel like i am calling the same elements on the dom  more then i should ....is there anyone that can think of a better way to achieve what i want without making all these calls

Comment: That code is not valid: (1) you end the `$.get...` line with a semi-colon, but you need a comma there, (2) the three variables in the get callback are local so they are undefined later in the code. Also you have `data[0]` three times in a row?! And `current_id` is never used?!

Answer (score 3):

You could cache the prettyCheckBox items:

```
function update_prices(that, current_id, quantity) {

    //that == $(this)

    var $wrapper = that.parents(".wrapper"),
        $prettyCheckBox0 = $wrapper.find(".prettyCheckbox small:eq(0)"),
        $prettyCheckBox1 = $wrapper.find(".prettyCheckbox small:eq(1)"),
        $prettyCheckBox2 = $wrapper.find(".prettyCheckbox small:eq(2)"),
        standard = $prettyCheckBox0.parents("span").parents("label").prev("input").val(),
        professional = $prettyCheckBox1.parents("span").parents("label").prev("input").val(),
        premium = $prettyCheckBox2.parents("span").parents("label").prev("input").val();    

    $.get("/shop_possystems/index.php?route=module/cart/ajax_get_individual_prices&standard_id=" + standard + "&professional_id" + professional + "&premium_id" + premium + "&quantity" + quantity,
        function(data) {
            var standard_price = data[0];
            var professional_price = data[0];
            var premium_price = data[0];
    });

    $prettyCheckBox0.text(standard_price);
    $prettyCheckBox1.text(professional_price);
    $prettyCheckBox2.text(premium_price);

    return true;
}
```

Also, I fixed an error.  You had `quantity;` and it should be `quantity,`.

Answer (score 1):

I would add CSS classes to those inputs such as `standard`, `professional`, and `premium`, and then all of your jQuery should look like:

```
function update_prices(that, current_id, quantity) {
     //that == $(this)
    var jqWrapper = that.closest(".wrapper");

    var jqStandard = jqWrapper.find("input.standard");
    var standard = jqStandard.val();

    var jqProfessional = jqWrapper.find("input.professional");
    var professional = jqProfessional.val();

    var jqPremium = jqWrapper.find("input.premium");
    var premium = jqPremium.val();

    var get = "/shop_possystems/index.php?route=module/cart/ajax_get_individual_prices&standard_id=" + standard + "&professional_id" + professional + "&premium_id" + premium + "&quantity" + quantity;

    $.get(get, function(data) {
        jqStandard.val(data.standard_price);
        jqProfessional.val(data.professional_price);
        jqPremium.val(data.premium_price);
    });

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cache the list of checkboxes and work off of that instead of the `wrapper` object you're working off of now:

```
var smallCheckboxes = that.parents(".wrapper").find(".prettyCheckbox small");
```

In context, something like this:

```
function update_prices(that, current_id, quantity) {
    var smallCheckboxes = that.parents(".wrapper")
                              .find(".prettyCheckbox small");
    var standard = smallCheckboxes.eq(0).parents("span")
                                        .parents("label")
                                        .prev("input").val(); 
   //etc...
```